# How to keep CloudWatch alarm in red until Apache Airflow DAG task is in failed state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, amazon-cloudwatch, mwaa

I have a CloudWatch alarm that uses `DAGDurationFailed` metric which sends a notification for DAG failure and goes back to OK after some time.

I want to modify this CloudWatch alarm so that it doesn't go back to OK as long as there are failed tasks in the DAG.

What could be the best way to do this?
I can think of setting up a Lambda that checks for failed tasks and publishes them to CloudWatch.